# React useEffect hook - infinite loop with redux action that uses ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm using `useEffect` in combination with reduct actions. I'm aware that I have to extract the action function from the props and provide it as the second argument which generally works for bulk fetches. But if I use an ID from the props as well, it ends up in an infinity loop:

```
export function EmployeeEdit(props) {
  const { fetchOneEmployee } = props;
  const id = props.match.params.id;
  const [submitErrors, setSubmitErrors] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => fetchOneEmployee(id), [fetchOneEmployee, id]);

  const onSubmit = employee => {
      employee = prepareValuesForSubmission(employee);
      props.updateEmployee(employee._id, employee)
          .then( () => props.history.goBack() )
          .catch( err => setSubmitErrors(extractErrors(err.response)) );
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <h3>Edit Employee</h3>
        <NewEmployee employee={props.employee} employees={props.employees} onSubmit={onSubmit} submitErrors={submitErrors} />
    </div>
  )
}

EmployeeEdit.propTypes = {
  fetchOneEmployee: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  employees: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  employee: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  employees: state.employees.items,
  employee: state.employees.item
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchOneEmployee, updateEmployee })(EmployeeEdit);
```

And the redux action:

```
export const fetchOneEmployee = (id) => dispatch => {
   axios.get(`http://localhost:8888/api/users/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
                const employee = res.data;
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_ONE_EMPLOYEE,
                    payload: employee
                })
        })
});
```

};

Anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see more of the component please?

Comment: updated with more code

Comment: if you remove `fetchOneEmployee` from the dependency array does it fix it?

Answer (score 0):

one of the values in your dependency array (`[fetchOneEmployee, id]`) is changing. It is hard to say which value it is with the limited code you have supplied.

At first glance though, you probably want `fetchOne` instead of `fetchOneEmployee` in your array.

Comment: that was a typo by copying the code over which I corrected

Answer (score 0):

Your inifite loop is probably caused because of fetchOneEmployee passed as argument to useEffect. Did you pass fetchOneEmployee to EmployeeEdit as arrow function? If you did then fetchOneEmployee always will be change.

This is a part of great article about react hooks fetch data.

> https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

I especially recommended header **CUSTOM DATA FETCHING HOOK**